# External hard drive how to format it?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems, operating-systems

I just bought a hard drive of 500GB that I want to use on Mac OS X and GNU/Linux but be able to use some file on Windows.

Basically I have to deal with FAT32 (That doesn't support file over 4GB), NTFS without Mac OS writting support, HFS (Not working on Windows) and EXT3 (Not working on Mac OS X)

How should I do ? Having a NTFS partion, a HFS+ partition, a EXT3 partition and a FAT32 partition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go with an ext3 and mount it in [Windows](http://www.fs-driver.org/) and [Mac OS](http://arssporadica.blogspot.com/2009/02/mounting-ext3-paritions-in-mac-os-x.html). I've used the Windows software before, worked fine, I can't personally vouch for ext2/3 on Mac OS, but it appears a valid solution.

Answer (score 5):

Use NTFS and Install [ntfs3g](http://www.ntfs-3g.org/) on your mac.

Comment: and use ntfs3g on linux as well...

Comment: This is not bad as well. But I don't like so much Microsoft software.

Comment: ntfs3g is not Microsoft software - it was independently developed.

Comment: An advantage of this is, that installing ntfs3g on linux is quite easy with the package management tool of your distribution. Installing a driver on windows requires you to browse to the website, download and reboot.

Comment: Unless you have it on your USB key or somewhere. By the way I know that ntfs3g is an open source project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have snow leopard?  If so, install the boot camp drivers on the machine....  When you are in Windows, put in your Snow Leopard DVD, and the boot camp drivers should install automatically...  They include HPFS drivers which should allow you to read/write to the Macintosh partitions...